# Changing MAMP passwords for MySQL

Tags: macos, mac, mamp

How do I change the MAMP MySQL password on the Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## How can I change the password of the MySQL root user?
>
> Open the Mac OS Terminal Application (located in "/Applications/Utilities") and enter the following command line:
>
> > /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password `<NEWPASSWORD>`
>
> replace `<NEWPASSWORD>` with your new password.
>   Please bear in mind that you also have to change the phpMyAdmin configuration and probably your own php-scripts to use the newly created MySQL password. For changing the phpMyAdmin configuration edit the following file and update the password:
>
> > /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin-X.X.X/config.inc.php

Source: [MAMP FAQ](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q9)

Comment: I get an error saying 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: I changed succesfully changed the password with `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password [NEWPASSWORD]`.  But the MAMP start page could not start the MySQL server with the new password.  It does if I change the password back.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the `<NEWPASSWORD>`-part, it's fixed now. MAMP cannot longer connect to your database, because you have to change every occurrence of your old password in all the config files.

Comment: I updated the phpmyadmin config.inc.php file what are the other config files that I must update?

Comment: A good idea might be to search the entire directory for files containing `<OLDPASSWORD>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The MAMP servers must be running while you make your changes in terminal. Note: after you enter your new password it will ask you for your password. Enter the old one. Probably "root".
2. Then enter the new password in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc online 86 delete root and replace with your new password.
3. Then open /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/index.php and on line 5 change the second root to your new password.
4. Then open /Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh and here look for proot and replace the root with your new password. leave the p.

Done.

Comment: Quick note: that path should read "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php".